# would this be safe to control servo with usb

Tags: current, usb, servo, basic, amperage

i've been asking around and people has been telling me that the max current a usb can supply is 100 ma then 200 ma then 500ma then the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB says 0.5–0.9 A (general) 5 A (charging devices)

i need control and supply a small servo with no load current of 100ma and stalling current of 900ma, how safe is that, do i need a fuse ?

Comment: I'd be most concerned about the motor causing an inductive spike that punches out your USB port. A fuse alone will not save you from that. You need a properly designed inductive-load circuit.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK 500mA is max for USB 2.0. Those higher current numbers are for USB 3.0. I made a few devices for USB 2.0, and fuses are always good, and also the ports have some internal over voltage mechanism.